# FMDB insert or replace do multiple entries

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I have an sqlite3 table, every time I run my code, it adds multiple entries. How can I change this query to add only one entry?

```
CREATE TABLE "GroupTable" (
    "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "memberId"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    "adminId"   TEXT NOT NULL,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

The method below shows how I am adding data:

```
func addDatatoList(info: ListModel ) -> Bool
    {
        sharedInstance.database!.open()
  
        let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate("INSERT or REPLACE INTO GroupTable(adminId, memberId, name) VALUES (?,?,?)", withArgumentsIn: [ info.adminId,info. memberId,info.name])
        sharedInstance.database!.close()
        return isInserted
    }
```

Comment: You generally don't have to open and close the database for every SQL statement. SQLite is pretty good about committing changes to the file as you go along...

Answer (score 1):

You’re not supplying an `id` value, so `INSERT OR REPLACE` will never replace. You theoretically could add `id` parameter, passing `NSNull()` if the `id` value is NULL

```
func addDatatoList(info: ListModel) -> Bool {
    guard let db = sharedInstance.database else { return false }

    db.open()
    defer { db.close() }

    let sql = "INSERT or REPLACE INTO GroupTable(id, adminId, memberId, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    let values: [Any] = [info.id ?? NSNull(), info.adminId, info.memberId, info.name]
    let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsIn: values)

    return isInserted
}
```

That having been said, if you did `INSERT`, you probably want to retrieve the row’s auto increment id value:

```
func addDatatoList(info: ListModel) -> Bool {
    guard let db = sharedInstance.database else { return false }

    db.open()
    defer { db.close() }

    let sql = "INSERT or REPLACE INTO GroupTable(id, adminId, memberId, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
    let values: [Any] = [info.id ?? NSNull(), info.adminId, info.memberId, info.name]
    let isInserted = sharedInstance.database!.executeUpdate(sql, withArgumentsIn: values)

    if isInserted, info.id == nil {
        let id = db.lastInsertRowId

        // e.g., if `ListModel` is a reference type and `id` is mutable, 
        // you might update the value, e.g.

        info.id = Int(id)
    }

    return isInserted
}
```

But, then again, if you're now programmatically determining whether you inserted or updated, you might as well have two SQL statements, one for `INSERT` and one for `UPDATE`.

Comment: my id is auto incremental ,does it need to be pass ?

Comment: also second method insert 1 value only not working with loop insert values

Comment: @9to5ios - “my `id` is auto incremental ,does it need to be pass ?” If you are inserting a record, no, it is not needed. But you are doing `INSERT OR REPLACE`, which suggests that you want to `INSERT` if it is a new record, but `REPLACE` if it is to update an existing record. And if you're updating an existing record, then obviously you have to supply the `id`, or else it won't know what record you are replacing. SQLite is clever enough to figure out that you want to `INSERT` if `id` is `NULL`, but `REPLACE` if it is not `NULL`.